# inserting data from form into my sql databse with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

Hello I have written a code to insert data from a form to mysql database :

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=data12;host=$servername", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$ul = $_POST['fname'];
$sql="insert into t22 values('16',".$ul.")";
```

The record is added but the value is empty.
I have also tried other syntaxes like :

```
$sql="insert into t22 values('16',$ul)";
$sql="insert into t22 values('16','".$ul."')";
$sql="insert into t22 values('16',$ul)";
```

please help me about that.

Comment: What does `$_POST['fname']` contain? Show your HTML form.

Comment: Also... you've found PDO, but not prepared queries? Seriously? The correct usage would be `$sql->prepare("INSERT INTO t22 VALUES (?,?))";` and `$sql->execute(['16',$_POST['fname']]);`

Comment: i have also added $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO t22  VALUES ('10',:fname)"); and it is interesting that  if I use :  $u='testtt';   $stmt->bindparam(':fname',$u ); it will work but when i use $u = $_POST['fname']; instead of  $u='testtt'; it will not work. I echo also the $u after post command and it has value but the value will not intered to database.

Comment: Like I asked before: ***What** is the value of* `$_POST['fname']`? And what is the type of the column you're inserting it to?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=data12;host=$servername", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$ul = $_POST['fname'];
$id = 16;


$sql="INSERT INTO t22 (data1,data2) VALUES(?,?)";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(array($id,$ul)); 

?>
```

*Change data1 and data2 with the names of the columns*

This works for me. 
I am sure it works for you!

Comment: @hosseinpink Feel free to check my answer as Correct :D

Comment: this is a mess.

Comment: how do you mean? @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: You are aware that you could use placeholder for your sql values.

Comment: Yeah that is possible but for now this works for him

Comment: Thats a temporary solution, you want him coming back again asking about placeholders?

Comment: No, just edit it as you think it must be :), I can learn something from it too then.

Comment: Now I see what you ment! It is to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Well yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first to make sure that empty values are not inserted, you need to check if that value is set from the form then execute the query when the value is set, also you need to prepare your statements when using PDO, also don't directly enter you variables in your query use placeholders instead.

This how you code should look:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=data12;host=$servername", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$errors = "";

$number = 16;

if (isset($_POST['buttonName'])) {

    //check if the field is not empty


    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {

        echo "enter name";
        $errors++;
    } else {


        $ul = $_POST['fname'];
    }

    if ($errors <= 0) {//no errors lets insert

        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO t22 (id,name) values(?,?)");
        $sql->execute(array(
            $number,
            $ul
        ));

        echo "record entered";
    }

}

?>
```

Hope this can point you on the correct direction.

> NB: its important that you filter and sanitize $_POST values before
>   storing them.